Bootstrap buttons are not clickeable
I have an issue with bootstrap buttons, i cant make click in them
i try to add a cursor: pointer and even with that, the buttons in my component of angular are not clickeable, i try to install bootstrap with npm i and add the styles in the "angular.json" file like this

And these are some of the buttons that are not clickeable in the component



Post your code as snippets instead of images. 2. Define the button is not clickable, when you click the button, did the button focused as the same behavior in Bootstrap 5 button? Have you tried to add (click) event with console.log to check whether the button is clicked?

